# Make deployment ActiveX control with using ClickOnce for Web

Tags: deployment, com, activex, clickonce

I need to make deployment our ActiveX control(two .dll files) through Web with using ActiveX. I saw that deployment .NET application with using ClickOnce is very easy, just need in VS click Build->Publish, but I can't find how I can make it with ActiveX.

Thanks, Roman

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible, the point of ClickOnce is to not alter the configuration of the target machine in any way.  Quite the opposite of what is required to get an ActiveX component functioning, it has to be registered and that requires altering the registry with an admin account.